# How to get tags of a youtube video using selenium?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

so, I'm trying to get the tags from a youtube video using python, but i have no idea how i can even approach this. Any suggestions would be highly appreciated, I'm trying to use selenium, is it feasible or would I be better off using the youtubeAPI?

Comment: You should use the YouTube API.